# PHP and Gettext don't work on my server

Tags: php, apache, gettext

I have a website. I'm  trying to get gettext to work so that my English, Sweden and Norway sites can come up.  I can't get it to work. What have I done wrong?

This is my config code:

```
// define constants ( defualt - danish )
$lang = 'da_DA';
$lang_short = '';
$lang_prefix = 'da';

if ( isset( $_GET['lang'] ) )
{
    switch( $_GET['lang'] )
    {
        case 'en':
            $lang = 'en_EN';
            $lang_short = 'en/';
            $lang_prefix = 'en';
            break;
        case 'se':
            $lang = 'se_SE';
            $lang_short = 'se/';
            $lang_prefix = 'se';
            break;
        case 'no':
            $lang = 'no_NO';
            $lang_short = 'no/';
            $lang_prefix = 'no';
            break;
    }
}
define( 'LANG', $lang_short );
define( 'LANG_PREFIX', $lang_prefix );

putenv("LC_ALL=". $lang );
bindtextdomain('messages', ROOT .'lang/');
```

And my path is `/var/www/rssbot.dk/lang/`. Should I make chmod right, or...?

Comment: Where did you place the .mo files under `lang`? Do you have a `/var/www/rssbot.dk/lang/en_EN/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo`? Also try `locale -a` to see if all the locales are available.

Comment: Yes to "path" and to locale -a its return ( C
en_GB.utf8
en_US.utf8
POSIX
 )

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I'm not sure en_EN is a valid locale. Try `en_US` or perhaps just `en` which should be region neutral. You may also have to install other locales than English on your OS to get the other languages working.

Comment: Just out of curiosity are the *message ids* in your code written in one of these languages or are they just place holder strings?

Comment: Hmmm its still not work :/ how can i test about i have a troble?

Answer (score 4):

I've found that some gettext installs need to have `locale-gen` run for each locale you want to use. I found this to be true for Ubuntu in particular. You might need to restart PHP (apache) after running `locale-gen`.

```
sudo locale-gen se_SE
sudo locale-gen no_NO
```

I've have a [test setup](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9535/gettext_test.zip) (with working locale files) that can determine if you gettext setup is working.

```
<?php

//Depending on your OS, putenv/setlocale/both will set your language.
putenv('LC_ALL=es_MX');
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'es_MX');

bindtextdomain( "su", "./locale" ); //set the locale folder for a textdomain
bind_textdomain_codeset( "su", "UTF-8" ); //set the codeset for a textdomain
textdomain( "su" ); //choose a textdomain

if( gettext("Hello World!") === "Hola a todos!" ) {
    print "We translated it correctly";
} else {
    print "Gettext setup isn't working";
}

?>
```

Comment: This worked for me as well! I'm running a LAMP stack using docker containers (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS). Here is an interesting discussion which ultimately led me to this answer on SO: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=66265

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that might go wrong.

1- To accomodate most systems, you need the following lines:

```
<?php 
$newlocale = setlocale(LC_MESSAGES, "sv_SE"); 
putenv("LANG=$newlocale");
?>
```

2- On Linux, when using setlocale with **LC_ALL** instead of **LC_MESSAGES**, you will need to have the locale installed on the server!

*It can be installed with a command like this one (for Ubuntu)*

```
aptitude install language-pack-sv
```

*Or just re-configured with a command like this one*

```
sudo locale-gen sv_SE
```

3- Specify the name of .mo files and locale directory

```
<?php
// Use default.mo located at ./locale/LC_MESSAGES/default.mo
bindtextdomain( "domain", "./locale" );
?>
```

4- When mixing single and double quotes while using gettext() or _(), your will need to use two bindtextdomain!

```
<?php
// Double quote _("Hello world") is matched
bindtextdomain( "domain", "./locale" );
// Single quote _('Hello world') is matched
bindtextdomain( 'domain', "./locale" );
?>
```

5- Encoding might be an issue in many places. If your .mo file is not in the same encoding (utf-8 for example) than your PHP script, it might not match!